# Parsing Issue-XML java

Tags: java, xml

I am currently working on an XML document from a website and I am trying to create a program that reads student ID and outputs 001. I have listed the XML document and my code which currently outputs nothing. I am able to get values like Tom and male, but not 001. How do I read information from the tag name student id?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
    <student id="001">
        <name>Tom</name>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <!-- Tom is a cat -->
    </student>
    <student id="002">
        <name>Jerry</name>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <!-- Jerry is a mouse -->
    </student>
</students>
```

```
package project;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = builder.parse("students.xml");
            // looks through any document that has accsysml tag
            NodeList nameList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student id");
            // count through different element types
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element studentItem = (Element) nameList.item(i);
                System.out.println(studentItem.getAttribute("id"));

            }
            NodeList name1List = doc.getElementsByTagName("students");
            // count through different element types
            for (int i = 0; i < name1List.getLength(); i++) {
                Node p = name1List.item(i);
                // name what element type it is
                if (p.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) p;
                    String kind = element.getAttribute("students");
                    Element element1 = (Element) p;
                    // prints value in element
                    System.out.println(kind + " " + element1.getTextContent());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no elements with tag name `"student id"`, because tag names cannot contain spaces. Try again.

Comment: I see. In my next step, I want to make go through a bunch of xml files and only parse through the documents with the tag "student id" so I thought outputting 001 would be a good start.

Comment: No I did not, I am very new at this language please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with the XML sample provided, you could use something like this (note how the `id` attribute is applied in this code:

```
try {
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = 
             javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document document = db.parse(new java.io.File("Students.xml"));
    org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("student");
    for(int x = 0,size = nodeList.getLength(); x < size; x++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(x).getAttributes()
                           .getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()); // HERE :)
    }
}
catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException | java.io.IOException | javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```